# Is there a "best" combination of buildings to maximize earnings for Super Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

As you level your castle and collect more toads via Toad Rally - more buildings open up as optional purchases. Some of these house toads of the same color and every so often, one will be standing outside of the house with a coin for you to redeem. Some houses take up one space, some two.

Is there a *best practice* for how I should stack these buildings?
Do I need to buy multiple homes of one color/type?

Comment: Note that the few coins that you get from those houses are pretty much irrelevant. You'll get in the general range of 300 to 900 coins per run on a lot of the Rally levels when you get good at them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to buy the buildings they are only purely cosmetic. They are just there for decoration. Every now and then the buildings will have a coin for you to collect.

Comment: So they are not "coin producing" items? What causes the coins to spawn, then? Is it a timer? Toad Rally  earnings?

Comment: I believe its just random.

Comment: Some buildings open up new levels as well as mini games. They're not just for decoration.